# Print Tuple into a DataFrame at end of Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tuples, linear-regression

I'm trying to print my information into a Dataframe. When I use the code below, I get the

SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the print statement.

The Code works if print (i, slr.coef_) without the dataframe call in front of it

````
for i in qual_train.columns:

    X = qual_train[[i]]
    y = train['SalePrice']

    slr = LinearRegression()
    slr.fit(X, y)

    print pd.DataFrame(i, (slr.coef_))```
````

Comment: On which line are you getting that error?

Comment: @abhilb I'm getting the error on the print statement. The function runs if I print (i, (slr.coef_)) , but I want my print statement to be a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in qual_train.columns:
   df=pd.DataFrame()

    X = qual_train[[i]]
    y = train['SalePrice']

    slr = LinearRegression()
    slr.fit(X, y)
    df['i']=pd.Series(i)
    df['coef_']=pd.Series(slr.coef_)

    print (df)
```